# Migrated question actually closed instead of 'on hold'? So how can it be improved?

Tags: discussion, support, specific-question, migration

Question [What forum-management software can I use?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11469/what-forum-management-software-can-i-use/13479#comment18597_13479) was migrated from https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/155556/revisions, then put on hold.

The OP now says in a comment that he cannot edit it to improve it because it is locked. 
The system says:

> This question came from our site for users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems.. Votes, comments, and answers are locked due to the question being closed here, but it may be eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated.

Sounds weird to me. The question should be here (so migration OK), but we also want users to be able to improve their questions, so that they can be reopened.

It *should* not be 'eligible for editing and reopening on the site where it originated', because it belongs here. It *is* not ...., because it no longer exists over there.

What can be done to make it a valuable question **here**?

Comment: Essentially the migration from unix.se got rejected. I need to confirm this but these sort of questions still get closed i think

Comment: Still unclear is the fact it even *states* migration was rejected, but it's still shown on *our* (the proposed target) site. So if migration was rejected, shouldn't the post be were it "came from"? Especially confusing to new users as it is now.

Comment: Migrations are strange beasts. I'm going to try unlocking it and see if it breaks anything.

Comment: Okay, I unlocked it here. Looks like that unrejected the migration and left it closed here. Can someone confirm that it can be edited now?

Comment: @Undo I just edited it (waiting for review now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A migrated question only lives on one site. Migrating locks the question on the original site and creates it on the target site. When a migrated question is closed (for any reason other than duplicate) on the receiving side, the migration is marked as rejected: the question again belongs to the sending site and is unlocked there (where it remains closed, since it's as off-topic as it was in the first place). When a migration is rejected, it is locked on the target site that rejected it, to avoid having two diverging copies of the same question.

While [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/11469/what-forum-management-software-can-i-use) is marginally on-topic on its original site [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/), inasmuch as it concerns software that would run on some Unix variant, the Unix aspect is marginal, so this question is better suited to Software Recommendations. Furthermore the [U&L question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155556/what-forum-management-software-can-i-use) has now been deleted (stubs of migrated questions are deleted automatically after a month). So we should work on this question here on SR.

Undo has unlocked the question, it can now be edited. I've cleared the migration history, to avoid any further trouble. (Both actions are moderator-only actions.)

The question is still severely lacking in information that would make it answerable. There are a great many forum implementations out there, and most include features to combat trolling. In order to be viable, the question needs to be edited to include a reasonable set of concrete requirements, such as:

- Protocols (e.g. web-based, email, NNTP, …)
- Message management (threads, groups, …)
- Privilege management (who gets to do which moderation activities)
- Expected moderation features (deletion or edition of messages, account suspension or banning, etc.)

Only software recommendations are on-topic here, books and papers are not. Questions about the human side (how to effectively use such software) — the actual questions on the topic, not questions asking where to find answers — are best asked on [Moderators Stack Exchange](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/).